# Can't start Rails application with the needed Ruby version with RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I tried to deploy my first Rails 3.x app on my VPS which was not really successful. On my VPS I use Apache and Passenger, but when I start the application, I get errors like:

```
/var/www/my_domain_name/sample_app/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND wrap_parameters format: [:json] ^
```

with a backtrace:

```
0   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    245 in `load'
1   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    245 in `load'
2   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    236 in `load_dependency'
3   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    245 in `load'
4   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb    588 
5   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb    587 in `each'
6   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb    587 
7   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb 30  in `instance_exec'
8   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb 30  in `run'
9   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb 55  in `run_initializers'
10  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb 54  in `each'
11  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb 54  in `run_initializers'
12  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb   136 in `initialize!'
13  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb  30  in `send'
14  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb  30  in `method_missing'
15  /var/www/slovnyky.com/sample_app/config/environment.rb  5   
16  config.ru   3   in `require'
17  config.ru   3   
18  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb    51  in `instance_eval'
19  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb    51  in `initialize'
20  config.ru   1   in `new'
21  config.ru   1
```

I figured out that the problem could be in the wrong Ruby version because 1.8.7 does not correctly recognize some hash syntax. But that is strange, cause it should not be using the preinstalled Ruby 1.8.7, but 1.9.3. On my CentOS 6.2 I installed RVM and Ruby 1.9.3, so I have this:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
rvm list
rvm rubies
=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

so it's strange that I get:

```
sudo ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Which is why I think that for some reason Passenger picks up the wrong Ruby version. When I try to start the server like:

```
rails server
```

it works and I can access my application via MY_IP:3000 without any problems.

So the question is: How do I make Passenger load the needed Ruby version, not the preinstalled one?

This is tail of Apache error_log after restart:

```
[Thu Jul 26 20:29:10 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jul 26 20:29:11 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jul 26 20:29:11 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jul 26 20:29:11 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Jul 26 20:29:11 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/3.0.12 PHP/5.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Answer (score 1):

Check "**PassengerRuby**" option in apache config. This option allows one to specify the Ruby interpreter to use. Source: [Configuring Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_configuring_phusion_passenger)

Comment: I've already tried to add PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby, but only to httpd.conf (nothing changed). Then tried to add PassengerRuby to passenger.conf and restarted Apache and it did something, but application still does not work. I got error: "The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected." Then I checked Apache error log and found such line "You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries." I tried to reinstall ruby - did not help. BUT I can run rails server and application works. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you precompile assets? Execute ```rake assets:precompile```

Comment: I tried and than it turned out that I had some css merge problems. I solved it, precompiled assets successfully, but error remained: "The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected." Here is what I get now [application error](http://slovnyky.com/)

Comment: Your passenger gem is in _/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/_ And you use ruby 1.9.3 from  _/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_ Try install passenger with ruby-1.9.3 and change passenger.conf in Apache (option **PassengerRoot**)

Comment: That did not help. Anyway, the path is correct. Currently I have /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12 in Apache config file. Tried to replace it with /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14, but that just gave default Apache page, as if Passenger never functioned, so I replaced it back to the previous path.

Comment: It looks like one gem is absent. Do you execute ```bundle install```? Need more info about error. Can you post here tail of apache error.log after restarting?

Comment: I've added tail of apache_log after restart. Have no idea where is the problem. Maybe, problem is with my hands and incorrect Passenger configuration (maybe, it needs something extra), cause with WEBrick I can start everything on my VPS without any problems.

Comment: Try to start passenger standalone: ```passenger start``` And look what happens.

Comment: Tried. Happened the same as when I start WEBrick - server starts and my application is available at the address MY_IP:3000. But still does not work with Apache.

Comment: For experiment I repeated from begin:  
1. clear installation ubuntu-server-12  
2. installation rvm (multi-user) - http://rvm.io  
3. installation ruby1.9.3, bundler, passenger  
4. installation apache2 with passenger module - http://www.modrails.com/install.html  
5. deploying application / creating db / precompiling assets  
It works as expected. I have no idea anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start production server with

```
bundle exec [command]
```

It should take care of the dependencies.

Comment: Would you be so kind and write in more details what I have to do? I ran bundle install after deploying application. I tried also to run bundle exec install, but that gave mistake.

Comment: what is the command that you use to run passenger? I use thin instead and the command to start thin is bundle exec thin start -C thin.yml. substitute [command] with your passenger start command.

Comment: It is started automatically (I use passenger with Apache).